# Knockout: remove all subscriptions from an observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, garbage-collection

I have an observable that I want to release the memory that is uses.
When setting in to null, the Garbage Collector is not collecting it becuase other he is referenced in some subscription.

The question is - how can I remove all the subscribers?

for example:

creating:

```
this.x = ko.observable();
```

removing:

```
this.x(null);
```

but it is not removed becuase it is referenced in some subscription:

```
this.y.subscribe(function (newValue) {
   var z = this.x();
};
```

I dont want to `dispose` the subscription - becacuse for a new value for `x` I want `y` to subscribe to it.

I hope it is clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've made a copy of its contents in code that does not update when `x` is updated. I realize you're just giving an example, but `subscribe` is generally a code smell, and your situation suggests to me that you should be making a `computed` that would update when `x` changes, which would solve your problem.

You cannot get rid of all the memory associated with `x` and at the same time keep a copy of its contents.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but how computed will help here?

Comment: If the subscription function were a computed, `z` would get the new value of `x` when `x` changed, so there would not be an old copy around.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks and Merry Chrismes